# How do I forcibly shut down a specific application at a pre-determined time?

Tags: macos, terminal, applications

I don't know if there's an available app or perhaps a terminal command, but I'd like to forcibly shut down a specific application at a specific time, without the option to cancel.

I'd like it so I can choose the time.

To make a long story short, there's a game that's incredibly addicting and if I don't force quit it, I can totally see myself getting lost in it for extra hours.

I'd rather just have the application quit, regardless of where I am in the game, so I make sure to follow through on my allotted time period for playing.

There's something similar, but not entirely applicable here (The info here could help in forming an answer):
[How can I forcibly shut down my Mac at an appointed time?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25001/how-can-i-forcibly-shut-down-my-mac-at-an-appointed-time)

Answer (score 1):

You can quit apps with AppleScript, such as:

```
osascript -e "tell application 'Safari' to quit"
```

Therefore, you can add the following to your crontab (`env EDITOR=nano crontab -e`) to quit an app without saving at 17:30 every day:

```
30 17 * * * /usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application 'Safari' to quit saving no"
```

If you want to quit without saving, you can remove the `saving no`.
Alternatively, you can kill the process with `/usr/bin/killall Safari`.

Comment: nice, what is missing is the "Force Quit" as per OP.

Comment: @Buscar OP did not refer to the specific action of Force Quit and therefore I interpreted it as the equivalent of 'shutdown' for the answer to the linked question. Regardless, I've edited my answer to include a force quit.

Comment: Thanks for the response !

So, lets say its 3:00 PM and I want the application to force quit, without saving, at 5:30 PM.

Then, I go into the AppleScript editor and type:
env EDITOR=nano crontab -e

And press enter.

Then, type: 
17 30 * * * /usr/bin/osascript -e "tell application 'App Store' to quit" saving no

Is that correct? Thanks again !

Comment: @Jacob I've edited my answer to clarify. `saving no` is part of AppleScript not osascript